# Conditional change value in cell in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace the NaN value for open, high and low to be same as close. However, this condition is applied only when the change is `0.00`

Below is my code

```
try:
    url = 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/AAME/chart/1y'
    q_data = pd.read_json(url)
    if q_data.change == 0.00:
        q_data.open = q_data.close
        q_data.high = q_data.close
        q_data.low = q_data.close
except Exception:
    print "No data"
    continue
```

The issue is the `try` loop is bypassed and goes to `except` loop.
How to change the data correctly?

Comment: Did one of the below solutions help? Feel free to accept one (tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest use non loop solution with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and chain boolean mask in `numpy` by broadcasting:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'close':[100] * 6,
                   'open':[4,5,4,5,np.nan,4],
                   'high':[np.nan,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'low':[1,3,5,7,np.nan,np.nan],
                   'change':[0,3,6,9,0,4],
                   'col':[np.nan]*6})

print (df)
   change  close  col  high  low  open
0       0    100  NaN   NaN  1.0   4.0
1       3    100  NaN   8.0  3.0   5.0
2       6    100  NaN   9.0  5.0   4.0
3       9    100  NaN   4.0  7.0   5.0
4       0    100  NaN   2.0  NaN   NaN
5       4    100  NaN   3.0  NaN   4.0

cols = ['open', 'high', 'low']
m  =  df[cols].isnull().values & (df['change'] == 0).values[:, None]

df[cols] = df[cols].mask(m, df['close'], axis=0)
#numpy alternative
#df[cols] = np.where(m, df['close'].values[:, None], df[cols])

print (df)
   change  close  col   high    low   open
0       0    100  NaN  100.0    1.0    4.0
1       3    100  NaN    8.0    3.0    5.0
2       6    100  NaN    9.0    5.0    4.0
3       9    100  NaN    4.0    7.0    5.0
4       0    100  NaN    2.0  100.0  100.0
5       4    100  NaN    3.0    NaN    4.0
```

**Explanation**:

There is problem chain `boolen DataFrame` with `boolen Series`, get error:

```
m  =  df[cols].isnull() & (df['change'] == 0)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (18,) (3,)
```

Solution is in [numpy broadcasting](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc):

```
print (df[cols].isnull().values)
[[False  True False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [ True False  True]
 [False False  True]]

print ((df['change'] == 0).values)
[ True False False False  True False]
```

So is necessary create N x 1 array:

```
print ((df['change'] == 0).values[:, None])
[[ True]
 [False]
 [False]
 [False]
 [ True]
 [False]]

m  =  df[cols].isnull().values & (df['change'] == 0).values[:, None]
print (m)
[[False  True False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [ True False  True]
 [False False False]]
```

Comment: could you elaborate more of `m  =  df[cols].isnull().values & (df['change'] == 0).values[:, None]
`? especially `(df['change'] == 0).values[:, None]`

Comment: Yes, give me some time.

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to structure your logic. There is no in-built function to `fillna` *dependent on other columns*, but you can reach the same result by combining Boolean arrays:

```
df = pd.read_json('file.json')

mask = (df['change'] == 0).values

for col in ['open', 'high', 'low']:
    col_mask = mask & df[col].isnull().values
    df.loc[col_mask, col] = df.loc[col_mask, 'close']
```

---

**Performance benchmarking**

Loops can be faster than apparently vectorised methods. Some `pandas` expert may be able to shed light on the performance difference. Data from @jezrael.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'close':[100] * 6,
                   'open':[4,5,4,5,np.nan,4],
                   'high':[np.nan,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'low':[1,3,5,7,np.nan,np.nan],
                   'change':[0,3,6,9,0,4]})

df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

def jp(df):
    mask = (df['change'] == 0).values

    for col in ['open', 'high', 'low']:
        col_mask = mask & df[col].isnull().values
        df.loc[col_mask, col] = df.loc[col_mask, 'close']
    return df

def jez(df):
    cols = ['open', 'high', 'low']
    m  =  df[cols].isnull().values & (df['change'] == 0).values[:, None]
    df[cols] = df[cols].mask(m, df['close'], axis=0)
    return df

%timeit jp(df)   # 9.09 ms
%timeit jez(df)  # 13.4 ms
```

Comment: @jpp - there si always solution with `np.where`, can you add to your timings or I can do it?

Comment: hmmm, and here loops should be faster, because only 3 columns, if many columns I think not.

Comment: @jezrael, Please do add `numpy.where` benchmarking (to my answer or yours). I'm interested in knowing why the loop method is faster, it's surprising.